# Android Studio can't detect updates

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, android-studio, android-update-sdk

I have been using Android Studio 1.3 for a month, but I can't update it to the latest version. I have tried all possible channel options and tried restarting it, but I can't see any options for "download" or "update and restart".

I need the latest stable version without having to reinstall the software.

**When I visit: Help -> Check for updates:**

[image]

**version 1.3 is shown as the latest version:**

[image]

Comment: In which update channel it is now ?

Answer (score 0):

Try after changing the channel to **Stable**. Restart Android studio after applying the settings (Latest version has a "Check now" button but this version doesnt).

Make sure you have no OR correct proxy settings.

Comment: I have tried doing that. Same results. 
I don't understand what you mean by proxy settings. Please elucidate.

Comment: go to android studio settings and search http proxy. ensure you have the correct settings there.

Comment: or the worst case could be that it is a bug in v1.3 ... rather than breaking your head any more on this just uninstall this version and download and install latest. Dont import settings from this version when it prompts. Things should be smooth thereafter.